# Using Python / pandaSDMX to process & upload to Postgresql

Tags: python, postgresql, sdmx

I am seeking a way to take SDMX files (like here: http://www12.statcan.gc.ca/datasets/Alternative.cfm?PID=105929&EXT=SDMX) and process them into a Postgresql table.

I can use rsdmx (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rsdmx/index.html) for smaller datasets but for large ones we reach a number of limitations in R.

PandaSDMX (https://pandasdmx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) appears to resolve some of these issues, but I am not experienced in Python and can't seem to get the syntax to work.  I'm able to use Response.get() to load a local file as a response object but am not sure where to go to from there.

I know I need to apply the code tables (structure file) but I'm not sure how to do that or make it so I can use odo (http://odo.pydata.org/en/latest/) to send it to postgresql.

Hoping someone can help out or suggest another method to pursue.